# "Painless bargaining" procedure proposal, in the eyes of game-theory

Tags: game-theory

I thought about a procedure to set an accepted price of a bargain, that aimed to maximize the sides' satisfaction and minimized the face-to-face tiresome bargain process.

Let's call the sides a buyer and a seller. The idea is:

```
1) each side figure a range that he willing to pay/sell, and write it on a paper, for instance
2) the two sides reveal the ranges
3) if there is an intersection:
    3.1) the price is set to be the average of its range
   otherwise:
    3.2) if the lower bound price that the buyer is willing to pay is higher than the higher bound price of the seller:
        3.2.1) the price is set to be the average of these bounds
         otherwise:
        3.2.2) there is no deal
```

in addition, this procedure must be done only once; in case that there is no deal (3.2.2) the bargain is terminated.

Examples:

```
3.2) buyer - 200-230
     seller - 220-240
     the intersection is 220-230, so the price is 225
3.2.1) buyer - 200-230
       seller - 150-180
       buyer's lower bound is 200, seller's higher bound is 180, so the price is 190
```

I believe this procedure is very convenient of both sides, and because of the option of breaking the deal (3.2.1) both sides will give the best offers they willing to carry.
Is this correct, in the eyes of game-theory?

Comment: Seems to be a clever method to find fair prices. No clue whether the game theory can decide whether this is a valid procedure. But it seems very reasonable at first sight.

Comment: There is no reason for the high end of the seller's range or the low end of the buyer's range.  Why should the buyer have a minimum price?

Comment: what happens when the buyers maximum price is below the sellers minimum price for a legitimate reason. e.g. when crop failure is leading to food shortages and famine with prices too high for most people to afford. Can you build a system that detects the game being played has failed and can automatically decide when rationing and price caps should be introduced?

Comment: This does not seem to be a mathematical question.

Comment: Game theory catalogs this problem as "bilateral trading". There is plenty of negative results around it. See this [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myerson-Satterthwaite_theorem) on Wikipedia for an introduction to the seminal result.

Comment: @Ross Millikan - I believe that every seller for instance have a price that he want to get (upper bound), and a price that he can carry just to close another deal (lower bound). The range concept might help the bargain-sides become less greedy and more rational.
Another issue that should be defined is the size of the range, o.w the seller will use [x, infinity)

Comment: @James Arathoon - I don't thing that the bargain failure reason is important. Both sides can consider whenever important to then when choose their ranges; it should be reflected inside the ranges

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking each party to propose a price, the high end for the buyer and the low end for the seller, then splitting the difference.  The problem with this is that each one is tempted to propose a price that is not the limit of what they would accept.  If the seller raises his limit price by 10 he gets 5 more after the split.  He might miss out on a few sales when he goes by the buyer's limit but those sales are not very profitable anyway.  Another problem is when the seller sells the same thing to various buyers.  The number he quotes the first buyer may get out, giving future buyers an unfair advantage.

Comment: Right, the proposal must have incentive for the seller to set higher bound different then infinity, and 0 as a lower bound for the user.
I guess the key idea is making a smaller ranges to be more profitable.

About the other problem, the proposal indeed isn't fit to it - the ranges must be unknown